# g++ on MacOSX doesn't work with -arch ppc64

Tags: macos, g++, universal-binary

I am trying to build a Universal binary on MacOSX with g++. However, it doesn't really work. I have tried with this simple dummy code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

This works fine:

```
% g++ test.cpp -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -o test
% file test
test: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
test (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
test (for architecture ppc7400):    Mach-O executable ppc
test (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

However, this does not:

```
% g++ test.cpp -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -arch ppc64 -o test
In file included from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:44:28: error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:45,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:45:29: error: bits/c++locale.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:46:25: error: bits/c++io.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/ios_base.h:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:45,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/atomicity.h:39:23: error: bits/gthr.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ext/atomicity.h:40:30: error: bits/atomic_word.h: No such file or directory
...
```

Any idea why that is?

I am on MacOSX 10.6. I have installed Xcode 3.2.2 with all SDKs it comes with. GCC 4.2 is the default. GCC 4.0 produces some different errors, though behaves similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ppc64 support was dropped in Snow Leopard.  You can still use ppc64 if you build and link against the Mac OS X 10.5 SDK.

Try the following command at the command line:

```
g++ test.cpp -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -arch ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -isysroot/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 -o test
```

Or for the 10.4 SDK use:

```
g++-4.0 test.cpp -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -arch ppc64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -isysroot/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -DMACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.4 -o test
```

Note, if you want to use the 10.4 SDK, you will have to use gcc 4.0 (or g++4.0 ).  Apple's GCC 4.2 doesn't support the 10.4 SDK.

Comment: Well it's not really a GCC issue.  it's that there's no ppc64 in the MacOSX10.6.sdk, not that GCC doesn't support ppc64.  gcc *DOES* still support ppc64. There's just no C++ runtime with ppc64 support in the 10.6 sdk.

Comment: Cool, thanks for that! That command works. How would it look like with the 10.4 SDK? Because I can't get that to work.

Comment: Just note: The 10.4 SDK doesnt work out of the box with GCC 4.2 (only with GCC 4.0). See my answer here for details how to make it working for GCC 4.2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829365/compile-boost-as-static-universal-binary-lib/2831042#2831042 Maybe you can add that to your answer.